# Jquery Draggable - Maintain Position on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

My html and css is changed every 5 minutes vi a shell script and then the browser refreshes to update page to reflect changes.

I have added Jquery draggable to allow users to reposition div's but I am limited to using client side coding only as the server doesn't support PHP, JSP etc..

Is it possible to maintain div positions on browser reload, without server side code?

Comment: @Marcin I have tried a changing the way my CSS and HTML is update, but not luck there. I have investigated different options, but all point to DB's and server side code solutions. The only option I can think of is if the js updates the css dynamically based on draggable position. But I'm not sure how to implement.

Comment: Then why don't you run through those choices you have evaluated in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give [web](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-storage) [storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) a go. Won't work on older browsers, but assuming that this is just an aesthetic nicety it will take care of the majority of your users. The gist of how it would work is on every move, you'd write a position array to a key value, and on load you'd call back the values to set initial positions.

Comment: Or, he could just save the state at the point at which he triggers the reload. Surely there should be support for this in the modern frameworks by now?

Comment: @Bubbles Good suggestion, but this machine doesn't have internet access. Sorry, I should have mentioned.

Comment: @Rhys - shouldn't matter, since the keys are stored in the browser client. If the browser in question doesn't support it, then yeah it won't work.

Comment: @Marcin How would I accomplish that? If you can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never heard of an event that can be triggered specifically on page requests (it strikes me as a little odd that it would exist, since refreshes are in part meant to act as a page interrupt), so I kinda have my doubts that'd be possible. But anyway, I'd just trigger the web storage on drag stop, something akin to:

$(".selector").draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { 
       // code to save location info
   }
});

It has the added benefit of being fault tolerant in the event of an unexpected closing of the browser, if nothing else.

Comment: @Rhys I assumed you were triggering the reload via javascript. If so, just do the same in the same place you are doing the reload.

Comment: @Marcin It is a meta refresh in html. How would I write a statement to save the state? and where would it save to? Are you talking about updating the css from the current state via js? Im a little confused.

Comment: @Rhys No, I'm talking about having a block of code which is triggered periodically, which first saves the state, then triggers the refresh. Alternatively, have an onbeforeunload event handler which saves the state. In both cases, I would suggest that you use web storage (or where unavailable, set a cookie from javascript).